Getting Argument Error while trying to cancel a sidekiq job using Sidekiq::Status.cancel
Am trying to cancel a siekiq job. I used Sidekiq::Status.cancel(jid)
This is my Sidekiq::Status module
require 'sidekiq-status/version'
require 'sidekiq-status/sidekiq_extensions'
require 'sidekiq-status/storage'
require 'sidekiq-status/worker'
require 'sidekiq-status/client_middleware'
require 'sidekiq-status/server_middleware'
require 'sidekiq-status/web' if defined?(Sidekiq::Web)
require 'chronic_duration'

module Sidekiq::Status
  extend Storage
  DEFAULT_EXPIRY = 60 * 30
  STATUS = [ :queued, :working, :retrying, :complete, :stopped, :failed, :interrupted ].freeze

  class << self
    # Job status by id
    # @param [String] id job id returned by async_perform
    # @return [String] job status, possible values are in STATUS
    def get(job_id, field)
      read_field_for_id(job_id, field)
    end

    # Get all status fields for a job
    # @params [String] id job id returned by async_perform
    # @return [Hash] hash of all fields stored for the job
    def get_all(job_id)
      read_hash_for_id(job_id)
    end

    def status(job_id)
      status = get(job_id, :status)
      status.to_sym  unless status.nil?
    end

    def cancel(job_id, job_unix_time = nil)
      delete_and_unschedule(job_id, job_unix_time)
    end

    def delete(job_id)
      delete_status(job_id)
    end

    alias_method :unschedule, :cancel

    STATUS.each do |name|
      define_method("#{name}?") do |job_id|
        status(job_id) == name
      end
    end

    # Methods for retrieving job completion
    def at(job_id)
      get(job_id, :at).to_i
    end

    def total(job_id)
      get(job_id, :total).to_i
    end

    def pct_complete(job_id)
      get(job_id, :pct_complete).to_i
    end

    def message(job_id)
      get(job_id, :message)
    end
  end
end


Iam getting this error ->
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)
from /Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redis-5.0.6/lib/redis/commands/sorted_sets.rb:528:in `zrangebyscore'
This is my zrangebyscore in sorted_sets.rb
def zrangebyscore(key, min, max, withscores: false, with_scores: withscores, limit: nil)
        args = [:zrangebyscore, key, min, max]

        if with_scores
          args << "WITHSCORES"
          block = FloatifyPairs
        end

        if limit
          args << "LIMIT"
          args.concat(limit.map { |l| Integer(l) })
        end

        send_command(args, &block)
end

Here is the backtrace of the error
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redis-5.0.6/lib/redis/commands/sorted_sets.rb:528:in `zrangebyscore'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-status-1.1.4/lib/sidekiq-status/storage.rb:93:in `schedule_batch'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-status-1.1.4/lib/sidekiq-status/storage.rb:42:in `block in delete_and_unschedule'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:106:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:106:in `block in with'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:103:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:103:in `with'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq.rb:79:in `redis'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-status-1.1.4/lib/sidekiq-status/storage.rb:39:in `delete_and_unschedule'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-status-1.1.4/lib/sidekiq-status.rb:36:in `cancel'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/embellishments/app/models/background_job.rb:17:in `cancel_sidekiq_job'
/Users/pranathi.dabbara/embellishments/app/controllers/centraldesign/background_jobs_controller.rb:89:in `cancel_job'

'cancel_job' is my endpoint thta triggers when i try to cancel the job from FE and i used Sidekiq::Status::cancel(jid) in 'cancel_sidekiq_job' method.
Please help me solve this error and cancel a job.

Can you provide a full stacktrace? This likely has something to do with Separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0 but without a stacktrace we can't see where specifically the error is occurring.

@engineersmnky Thanks for the response.
I couldn't add backtrace here in comments so i edited it in the question. Please review it.

To add more, Iam trying to cancel a job that is currently running. @engineersmnky

the version of the  sidekiq-status gem you are using is not compatible ruby ruby 3 keyword arguments for zrangebyscore Source. You will need to update your version to at least 2.0 (current version is 3.0.3)
